# XPath - retrieve multiple values from different paths based on same condition

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-parsing

This is my XML

```
<root>
   <entry id="1">
      <value name="ID">11</value>
      <value name="ENABLE">0</value>
      <value name="NAME">USER1</value>
   </entry>
   <entry id="2">
      <value name="ID">11</value>
      <value name="ENABLE">0</value>
      <value name="NAME">USER2</value>
   </entry>
   <entry id="3">
      <value name="ID">12</value>
      <value name="ENABLE">0</value>
      <value name="NAME">USER1</value>
   </entry>
</root>
```

I need an XPath query to retrieve all the names whose `id` is **11**.

I tried:

```
String xpath = "/root/entry/value[@name=ID/text()='11']/value[@name='NAME']";
String xpath = "/root/entry/value[@name=ID/text()='11']/NAME";
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong in my query?

**EDIT:**

Expected Output:

```
USER1
USER2
```

both these have ID = 11

Comment: Please clarify with example expected output.  What do you mean by return all "names"?

Comment: My expected output is USER1 and USER2 since both have ID=11

Comment: Please see my post for the Java code needed to access all of the matched nodes instead of just the first one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be the correct path:

```
/root/entry[value[@name = 'ID'] = 11]/value[@name = 'NAME']
```

To retrieve a list of nodes, you need to use the version of xPath.evaluate() that takes a returnType parameter:

```
InputSource document = new InputSource(new FileInputStream("user1.xml"));
String xpath = "/root/entry[value[@name = 'ID'] = 11]/value[@name = 'NAME']";
NodeSet result = (NodeSet)xPath.evaluate(xpath, document, XPathConstants.NODESET); 
for(int index = 0; index < result.getLength(); index ++) {      
    Node node = result.item(index);
    String name = node.getNodeValue();
}
```

Comment: @Abi Sorry, I had an extra slash. Please try it now.

Answer (score 3):

```
/root/entry[value[@name="ID" and .=11]]/value[@name="NAME"]
```

or

```
/root/entry/value[@name="ID" and .=11]/../value[@name="NAME"]
```

or

```
/descendant::entry[value=11 and value/@name="ID"]/value[@name="NAME"]
```

or

```
//value[.=11]/@name[.="ID"]/ancestor::entry/value[@name="NAME"]
```

or many other variations

Comment: first option - infinite loop. second option - returns only one user USER1

Comment: fourth option also returns only one value

Answer (score 1):

**Use**:

```
/*/*[*[@name='ID'] = 11]/*[@name='NAME']
```

**XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select="/*/*[*[@name='ID'] = 11]/*[@name='NAME']"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<root>
    <entry id="1">
        <value name="ID">11</value>
        <value name="ENABLE">0</value>
        <value name="NAME">USER1</value>
    </entry>
    <entry id="2">
        <value name="ID">11</value>
        <value name="ENABLE">0</value>
        <value name="NAME">USER2</value>
    </entry>
    <entry id="3">
        <value name="ID">12</value>
        <value name="ENABLE">0</value>
        <value name="NAME">USER1</value>
    </entry>
</root>
```

**the XPath expression is evaluated and the result of this evaluation (all selected nodes) is copied to the output**:

```
<value name="NAME">USER1</value>
<value name="NAME">USER2</value>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is working but is XSL the only way to go about it? Cannot be done using normal XPath?Because when I tried using that Xpath in my class it returned only user1

Comment: @Abi Both Dimitre's example and mine should find USER1 and USER2.  If you're only getting one value, it's the way you're applying the XPath that's wrong. Please show us your actual code.

Comment: @JLRishe - yes that may be the mistake, code is    String xpath = "/root/entry[value[@name = 'ID'] = 11]/value[@name = 'NAME']";   
   String result = xPath.evaluate(xpath, new InputSource(new FileInputStream("user1.xml")));

Comment: @abi, the result from `evaluate()` most probably is Object -- and needs to be cast to a list of nodes. Your mistake is that you are assigning it to a String. I don't know what XPath API you are using (the PL seems to be Java) -- please, read well the documentation and review any available code examples, so that you can correct your current code.

Comment: MYBAD!!! didnt realize i had messed up in the reading the result part. Thanks alot for all your answers

Answer (score 0):

try this,

String xpath = "/root/entry[value[@name='ID' and text()='11']]/value[@name="NAME"]";

Comment: Nope,I am getting 11 as the output

Comment: i have missing NAME part,check it now

Comment: i am getting only one user value returned

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
//entry[value[@name = 'ID'] = 11]/value[@name = 'NAME']
```